# Image Editor control for Delphi

Tags: delphi, canvas, components, imaging

I'm looking for a free component that has simple image editing features like pan, zoom, selection with cursor, etc. I will use OpenCV in my project, but I don't want to struggle with implementing an imaging component that does those functions, I want to focus on only OpenCV. I don't need any effects, filter, etc. I only need a canvas surface like photoshop or ms paint. I can write a component from scratch that derives from TWinControl, but it will take my days, and bugs will be into the bargain. I've searched on Torry but I haven't find yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/) probably provides exactly what you need.

It comes with components that support layers, and there are some example applications to show how to use them.

It's totally free, open source, doesn't require external dll's, and it's fast. It works for both Delphi and FreePascal+Lazarus.

Note: the screenshots on the project page don't show any layer-stuff, but just pull the latest version from svn, and check out the "layers" folder under examples. There are 3 demo's under there.